# Группировка датафрейма

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Есть датафрейм с ежедневными данными df:

```
    date    quantity    sum
0   2021-12-30  2   10
1   2021-12-31  1   10
2   2022-01-01  1   11
3   2022-01-02  3   20
4   2022-01-03  1   12
5   2022-01-04  1   12
6   2022-01-05  1   12
7   2022-01-06  1   10
8   2022-01-07  1   10
9   2022-01-08  1   10
10  2022-01-09  1   10
11  2022-01-10  1   10
12  2022-01-11  1   10
13  2022-01-12  1   10
```

Нужно получить новый датафрейм df1 на основе этого, но понедельный
То есть сложить все данные всех столбцов кроме даты,
а в дату записать данные из последней строчки
Должно получится вот что

```
    date    quantity    sum
0   2022-01-05  10  87
1   2022-01-12  7   70
```

Не понимаю каким способом мне это сделать? Ни сводные таблицы, ни агрегация, ни фильтрация не наводят меня на мысль

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так понимаю, что недели у вас не привязаны к календарным, раз заканчиваются они в середине реальной календарной недели. Тогда нужно просто пронумеровать недели согласно номерам записей в датафрейме, сгруппировать по ним и взять нужные аггрегации:

```py
df['week'] = np.arange(df.shape[0]) // 7
df.groupby('week').agg({'date': 'last', 'quantity': 'sum', 'sum': 'sum'})
```

На выходе:

```
    date    quantity    sum
week            
0   2022-01-05  10  87
1   2022-01-12  7   70
```

Код для воспроизведения датафрейма:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = """id date    quantity    sum
0   2021-12-30  2   10
1   2021-12-31  1   10
2   2022-01-01  1   11
3   2022-01-02  3   20
4   2022-01-03  1   12
5   2022-01-04  1   12
6   2022-01-05  1   12
7   2022-01-06  1   10
8   2022-01-07  1   10
9   2022-01-08  1   10
10  2022-01-09  1   10
11  2022-01-10  1   10
12  2022-01-11  1   10
13  2022-01-12  1   10""".split('\n')
data = list(map(str.split, data))
df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0])
df.loc[:, ['quantity','sum']] = df.loc[:, ['quantity','sum']].astype(int)
```

Comment: Спасибо, завидую вашей компетентности, подозревал, что вопрос можно решить с помощью numpy, но совсем не разбираюсь в этой библиотеке, а пора бы уже!

Comment: @ДенисАстаховский `numpy` отличный для всяких "векторных" вычислений, да, нужно его учить, ага )

Comment: Вообще тут нужно бы ещё проверить, что сортировка по датам у вас правильная в датафрейме, вероятно нужно предварительно отсортировать датафрейм по дате.